# Why does the decorator return the type None?

Tags: python, python-decorators

Help me understand why this decorator does not add a value to the end of the list that is formed in the do_list () function.

I get the result of the function working with the decorator None

```
def dec_do_list(func):
    def wrapper(arg: int):
        result = func(arg).append(4)
        return result
    return wrapper
@dec_do_list
def do_list(arg: int):
    import random
    result = []
    for i in range(arg):
        result.append(random.random())
    return result

print(do_list(4))
```

Thank you in advance!

P.S.
I do this for educational purposes, in order to better understand the Decorator pattern

Comment: Hint: see where the code says `result.append(random.random())`, and **does not** say `result = result.append(random.random())`? Does that part of the code appear to work? What if you try using the same, known-working technique in the place where the problem occurs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
result = func(arg).append(4)
```

`append` doesn't return a new list. It modifies the list in-place. You are getting the `result` as the return value of `append` and then returning it so at the end the returned value is `None`.

You can change it to:

```
result = func(arg)
result.append(4)
return result
```

or, in one line:

```
return func(arg) + [4]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I also saw what my problem is, I read more carefully about the append list metho

Comment: @ВиталийАгарев Glad that I was able to help. If this post explains your doubts and solves your problem, please accept it as answer by clicking the checkbox.